# Eclipse CDT Oxygen with LLVM support forces stdc++

Tags: c++, llvm, ubuntu-16.04, eclipse-cdt, clang++

I have Eclipse CDT Oxygen on Ubuntu 16.04, with the LLVM support installed. LLVM 5.0.0 is installed, and I want to experiment with libc++. The problem is building a project with libc++, but without libstdc++.

The first step is building a simple "Hello World" executable using c++ and libc++. For the project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings I have the following:

```
LLVM Clang (all options): -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c11
LLVM Clang++ (all options): -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0  -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++17
LLVM Clang linker (all options): -v -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/ -nodefaultlibs
```

Note that "-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/" is added automatically and I cannot get rid of it.
The linked libraries are (in order): c++, c++abi, m, c, gcc_s, gcc, stdc++
The stdc++ lib is added automatically and seems impossible to strip out. This results in an executable that contains both libc++ and libstdc++ which we don't want. Does anyone know of a way to build a project without libstdc++ but with libc++ ?